# Why does Sanhedrin 95a not list the Kefitzas HaDerech example of the 10 spies in Shelach

Tags: rashi, talmud-bavli, travel, parashat-shelach, practical-kabbalah

Question inspired by R. Elchanan Shoff [Oneg Shelach](https://www.bklashul.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Oneg-37-Shelach-2019.pdf) 2019 p.6

[Rashi on Bamidbar 13:25](https://www.chabad.org/parshah/torahreading.asp?aid=2495752&p=2&showrashi=true&jewish=Shelach-Torah-Reading.htm) states

> "They returned from scouting the Land at the end of forty days: But
> does not the Land measure four hundred parasangs by four hundred
> parasangs [a parasang is equivalent to about three-and-a-half miles in
> length], and an average person’s daily traveling distance is ten
> parasangs? Thus, it takes forty days to walk from east to west, and
> they traversed its length and its breadth? **However, since it was
> revealed before the Holy One, blessed is He, that He would sentence
> them with a year for every day, he shortened the way [so they covered
> ground more rapidly]**. — [Mid. Tanchuma 8]"

BT [Sanhedrin 95a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.95a.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) lists three occurrences of Kefitzas HaDerech, but does not mention the Rashi example. Is there a rationale for the omission?

> "The Sages taught in a baraita with regard to land contracting to
> shorten a journey: For three individuals the land contracted, and each
> one miraculously reached his destination quickly: Eliezer, servant of
> Abraham, and Jacob our forefather, and Abishai, son of Zeruiah. The
> Gemara elaborates: The case of Abishai, son of Zeruiah, is that which
> we said. The case of Eliezer, servant of Abraham, is as it is written:
> “And I came that day to the well” (Genesis 24:42). His intention was
> to say to the members of Rebecca’s family that on that day he left
> Canaan and on the same day he arrived, to underscore the miraculous
> nature of his undertaking on behalf of Abraham. The case of Jacob our
> forefather"

Comment: For starters, the 10 spies didn’t get it because they were on a righteous mission like the other 3.

Comment: Presumably, the list is not meant to be exhaustive.